# Cakephp: Upload file with google drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to upload a file from local to google drive in my Cake PHP application. This function as a stand alone script runs without a problem but when I try to integrate it in the cakephp application it doesn't work. 
So it doesn't find any of these, they are null:

`if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {`

And the program exits with code 200.

This is the function in my cakephp application:

```
public function uploadFileToGoogleDrive($year, $month, $file_name, $full_path)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout(false);
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $client = new Google_Client();

    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('CLIENT-SECRET');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/myapp');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        } else{
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        }

        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

        //create the folder if doesn't exist
        //check if year folder exists:

        $parameters = ['q' => "name contains '".$year."' and mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"];

        $year_folders = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

        if (count($year_folders) == 0){
            $fileFolderMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
            $fileFolderMetadata->setName($year);
            $fileFolderMetadata->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

            $fileFolder = $service->files->create($fileFolderMetadata, array(
            'fields' => 'id'));
            //printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $fileFolder->id);

            //year folder id
            $year_folder_id = $fileFolder->id;

        }
        else{
            //year folder id
            $year_folder_id = $year_folders[0]->id;
        }

        //check if month folder exists

        $parameters = ['q' => "name contains '".$month."' and mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"];

        $month_folders = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

        if (count($month_folders) == 0){
            $fileFolderMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
                ['parents' => [$year_folder_id]]
            );
            $fileFolderMetadata->setName($month);
            $fileFolderMetadata->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

            $fileFolder = $service->files->create($fileFolderMetadata, array(
            'fields' => 'id'));
            //printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $fileFolder->id);

            //Insert a file
            $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
                ['parents' => [$fileFolder->id]]
            );
        }
        else{
            //Insert a file
            $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
                ['parents' => [$month_folders[0]->id]]
            );
        }

        $file->setName($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('Invoice');
        $file->setMimeType('application/octet-stream');

        $data = file_get_contents($full_path);

        $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
              'data' => $data,
              'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
              'uploadType' => 'multipart'
            ));
    }
    else{
        var_dump('failed: '.http_response_code());
    }
}
```

Comment: Never access superglobals in CakePHP directly, always use the abstracted interfaces provided by CakePHP! **[Query String Parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters)** / **[Accessing the Session Object](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object)**

Comment: @ndm I changed my code but still they are null

Comment: If you access the session via CakePHPs session object, then you don't have to start the session manually, so that will fix the problem that you've mentioned in your question. Something being `null` is a new problem that you haven't mentioned before. In order for anyone to be able to comment on that, you'll have to show your changes, and add a little more explanation as to what exactly is happening / what exatly you are doing, "_doesn't work_" isn't a sufficent problem description.

Comment: @ndm the problem is that if I run this function as a standalone application it works as expected, but it doesn't work when I integrate it in CakePHP application. And I haven't find any example of how to use Google Drive API in CakePHP